# React Testing Library using within together with custom query

Tags: react-testing-library

Is there any way to get custom queries using within? Custom queries works fine for render function using adapter module:

```
import { render, queries } from '@testing-library/react';

import * as customQueries from './custom-queries';

const customRender = (ui, options) =>
  render(ui, { queries: { ...queries, ...customQueries }, ...options });

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react';

// override render method
export { customRender as render };
```

But when I use within, it doesn't see my custom query, which in general would be expected. Is there any way how `within` can be extended with custom query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you have a `customRender`, you can have a `customWithin`:

```
const customWithin = (element) => within(element, { ...queries,...customQueries });
```